# Django Rest Framework and React Front End: How to prevent unauthorized users from viewing private images if they get a hold of the image URL?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

My understanding is that on a normal React website all the media will be served from the same server than the front-end files (HTML, CSS and Javascript).

The REST API backend will only provide links to where those images are stored, and it will be served and displayed by the front end.

The problem is if those images are private and only one user should be able to see them. If someone gets a hold of the image URL and opens it they would be able to see the image.

How do modern websites get around this problem? What would be the workflow between Django and React to keep the user's images safe and private?

Comment: Modern websites get around this by having ephemeral links. Example, photo links on Facebook are valid for few weeks/days depending on the link.

Comment: Another more private possible sollution is to have authentication gateway between users and  static file host. F.e.  you have file storage at s3 and your own authentication server. User request image from your server, your server check user token or something else, and pipe download stream from s3 to user.

Comment: Another one is to use nginx's X-Accel-Redirect header. It will be also so much hellpful for hide real images from user and control downloading.At first, user requests nginx with token, nginx redirects to your auth server, your auth server writes this redirects headers and returns response to nginx (f.e it includes path to your private storage with some keys), nginx catches this headers in response, uses them to download image from your private storage and removes it from final answer to user. So another user will 
 not have access to image if he will have only link, he will need token too

Comment: I just read a comment about that on ycombinator! Have a look at it https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23057465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Step 1: All requests for media should go throught a specific view

Edit file myproject/urls.py and add:

from myproject.views import media_access

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)', media_access, name='media'),
]


Step 2: Add the view and check access

Add the following view in myproject/views.py:

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

def media_access(request, path):
    """
    When trying to access :
    myproject.com/media/uploads/passport.png

    If access is authorized, the request will be redirected to
    myproject.com/protected/media/uploads/passport.png

    This special URL will be handle by nginx we the help of X-Accel
    """

    access_granted = False

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if user.is_staff:
            # If admin, everything is granted
            access_granted = True
        else:
            # For simple user, only their documents can be accessed
            user_documents = [
                user.identity_document,
                # add here more allowed documents
            ]

            for doc in user_documents:
                if path == doc.name:
                    access_granted = True

    if access_granted:
        response = HttpResponse()
        # Content-type will be detected by nginx
        del response['Content-Type']
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected/media/' + path
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Not authorized to access this media.')


Here the important part is about the variable user_documents. It should contain reference to all files the user has access. In my case I extended the User model to add a field identity_document that why I can access it here.

In this media_acces view, you can implement any authorization logic.


Step 3: Configure nginx

Here is a full example of nginx configuration. The important part is about location /protected/. We suppose that Django is available with Gunicorn on port 8080 for example.

upstream myprojectapp {
  server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name myproject.com;

    server_name_in_redirect on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myproject-error.log crit;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/myproject-access.log custom_combined;

    root /path/to/my/django/project/static;

    location ^~ /static/ {
        alias /path/to/my/django/project/static/;
    }

    location /protected/ {
        internal;
        alias /path/to/my/django/project/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://myprojectapp;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

}

You can notice there is no location ^~ /media/ that's because this URL is handle by django.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more like an addition to other's answer regarding `X-Accel`. `X-Accel` solved the first half of the problem, that is having a gatekeeper for the links.

The other half of the problem is that sometimes you won't be able to authenticate the users that easily, for example in a typical React/DRF setup you will be using JWT, and don't have control over which headers the browser will sent to your server. You will have the following options

1. You will need to either choose to use cookie-based authentication
2. Implement a custom authentication mechanism in the image link, similar to how AWS S3 pre-signed URL works. An easy way to do that is to generate the URL to the image according to Nginx `secure_link` module.
   Ref: https://www.nginx.com/blog/securing-urls-secure-link-module-nginx-plus/

I choose method #2, by having a custom field/serializer class (.i.e `SecuredFilePathSerializer`) and use it instead of `FilePathField`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, before the REST API endpoint serves the URL of images, the request and response of the endpoint can be properly authorized using the Django REST frameworks authorization framework.

Additionally, you can write your own custom Django middlewares [HTTP hooks] for your desired end goal.

The middlewares can custom the HTTP request-response behaviors based on your needs.